# Convert ECW to TIFF in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, ecw

I have been given an ArcGIS Pro file with an ECW. I would like to export that ECW as a TIFF so I can open it on more programs. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for converting an ECW to a geoTiff.  [Here are some instructions](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/export-or-convert-raster-datasets.htm) and [here as well](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm).  Your enhanced compressed wavelet (ECW) file is a file format that handles image compression efficiently.  This means your ECW file is likely quite large.  If this is the case you will get a huge tiff as an output.  If you still want to proceed you should pay export several smaller sections of the ECW at a time.  You can always build a vat file in QGIS to handle all the exported geotiffs for use in QGIS.

Comment: Output does not need to be huge. TIFF format supports compression, and JPEG compressed, tiled TIFFs with pyramid layers are not much bigger than ECW and about as fast to browse.